# Checking the format of the timestamp

Tags: php, utc

I have a timestamp string with me (1606031551). There are  n number of functions to convert a timestamp into UTC in php. But I could not find a method that checks whether the timestamp string is UTC in php. Can you please tell if there are any methods which determine whether the current timestamp string is UTC?

Answer (score 3):

Timestamps are simple integer that counts every second from Thursday, 1 January 1970. Unix timestamps are in UTC timezone. You cannot extract timezone from a simple integer number without any other information.

Comment: +1 and to be more specific, UNIX timestamps 'are in UTC' because they measure the time passed since [January 1, 1970 **UTC**](http://currentmillis.com/tutorials/system-currentTimeMillis.html#unix-timestamp)

Answer (score -1):

Timestamp should always be in UTC because it's pure int and you cannot pass timezone with it.

Comment: Yep but this is not an answer.